# Найти дублирующие услуги пациента в один день в коллекции

Tags: java, коллекции, java-stream

Есть коллекция `List<Uslugi>`, которая содержит список услуг пациентов.

Класс, описывающий услугу:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "uslugi")
public class Uslugi {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column
    private String polis;
    @Column
    private String fio;
    @Column
    private Date date_obsl;
    @Column
    private String code_usl;
    @Column
    private int kol_usl;
    @Column
    private boolean correct;

    // конструкторы/геттеры/сеттеры    
}
```

Может быть такое что одна и та же услуга в один день была выполнена пациенту более одного раза. Если такие услуги будут у пациента нужно для первой услуги в поле `correct` поставить значение `true`, а в поле `kol_usl` указать значение сколько раз эта услуга сделана пациенту в один день. А для остальных таких услуг, которые были сделаны в поле correct поставить значение `false`.

Как такое возможно реализовать?

Пыталась так пройтись по всем услугам для начала

```java
List<Usluga> list1 = list;
    
for (Usluga usluga : list) {
    for (Usluga usluga1 : list1) {
        if (usluga.getDate_obsl() == usluga1.getDate_obsl() && usluga.getCode_usl().equals(usluga1.getCode_usl())) {
            System.out.println("Исключено ");
        } else {
            System.out.println("не исключено ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Начать с малого - убрать из фрагмента кода то, что к вопросу не относится )

Comment: Далее непонятно, что у вас вызывает затруднения в тривиальном подходе - пройти по всем услугам идентифицировав те которые должны быть объединены (да даже просто попарно все проверив, это не так долго, если у вас не овер100500 услуг) и объединить их как вам надо.

Comment: Что по вашему мнению не относится к коду? Вроде все что относится оставила. Пациент проверяется по полису и фио, остальные поля тоже нужны

Comment: В вопрос добавила то как пыталась проверять дату и услугу

Comment: Вы так формулируете вопрос, будто ожидаете, что кто-то должен взять ваш код и за вас его дописать. То как именно вы идентифицируете пациента (по ФИО или по Полису - это кстати оба неправильных подхода) это детали, которые к вопросу не относятся.

Comment: Нет, я хочу понять какой алгоритм должен быть чтобы решить мою задачу

Comment: Алгоритм оперирует в терминах алгоритма (пример неоптимального, но рабочего варианта описал выше)

Comment: Я вроде так и делала как вы описали

Comment: Если так и делали - приводите код и конкретные проблемы с ним. А если `System.out.println("Исключено ");`, то говорить тут не о чем )

Comment: Т.е. я неправильно сравниваю? Мне нужно сравнить так. Взять услугу одного пациента и проверить была ли такая услуга ему указана в этот день еще раз. То что вы посоветовали тоже общее решение, не имеющее отношение к моей задаче.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала в коде используется некорректное сравнение разных дат при помощи оператора `==` вместо `.equals`: `usluga.getDate_obsl() == usluga1.getDate_obsl()`.

Также похоже, что основная проблема состоит в том, чтобы корректно сгруппировать по дням, когда используется устаревший класс `Date`, который фактически содержит информацию не о дате, а о моменте времени (аналоге `Instant`/`LocalDateTime` из JSR310 Date/Time API).  Фактически следует каким-либо образом получить экземпляр `LocalDate` из `Date` для поля `date_obsl`.

В условии не упомянуто, что входной список является отсортированным в каком-либо порядке, поэтому для обработки "дубликатов" услуг лучше будет отсортировать его по реквизитам пациента *и* по дате -- так будет проще выявить дубликаты по дням/пациентам за один проход.

Вариант решения с сортировкой входного списка.  При итерировании по списку определяем, выполняется ли условие группировки и при необходимости устанавливаем флажок `correct` в `false` и инкрементируем количество услуг.
Для конвертации в `LocalDate` используем `java.sql.Date::toLocalDate`:

```java
public static void fixUslugi(List<Uslugi> list) {
    if (null == list || list.size() < 2) {
        return;
    }

    list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Uslugi::getPolis)
            .thenComparing(Uslugi::getFio)
            .thenComparing(Uslugi::getDate_obsl)
            .thenComparing(Uslugi::getCode_usl)
    );

    for (int i = 0, n = list.size(); i < n; i++) { // n - кэшируем размер списка
        Uslugi curr = list.get(i);
        LocalDate currDate = new java.sql.Date(curr.getDate_obsl().getTime()).toLocalDate();
        curr.setCorrect(true);
        curr.setKol_usl(1);
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            Uslugi next = list.get(j);
            LocalDate nextDate = new java.sql.Date(next.getDate_obsl().getTime()).toLocalDate();
            if (!nextDate.equals(currDate) ||
                !curr.getPolis().equals(next.getPolis()) ||
                !curr.getFio().equals(next.getFio()) ||
                !curr.getCode_usl().equals(next.getCode_usl())
            ) {
                break;
            }
            // найден дубликат
            curr.setKol_usl(curr.getKol_usl() + 1);
            next.setCorrect(false);
            i = j;
        }
    }
}
```

Тест (для класса `Uslugi` используются Lombok-аннотации):

```java
List<Uslugi> list = Arrays.asList(
    new Uslugi(1, "p1", "John", new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 4*3600_000L), "usl1"),
    new Uslugi(2, "p2", "Jane", new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 5*3600_000L), "usl2"),
    new Uslugi(3, "p1", "John", new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 5*3600_000L), "usl1"),
    new Uslugi(4, "p1", "John", new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 28*3600_000L), "usl3"),
    new Uslugi(5, "p3", "John", new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1*3600_000L), "usl1"),
    new Uslugi(6, "p2", "Jane", new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 2*3600_000L), "usl2"),
    new Uslugi(7, "p3", "John", new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 3*3600_000L), "usl2"),
    new Uslugi(8, "p3", "John", new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 6*3600_000L), "usl3")
);

list.forEach(System.out::println);
System.out.println("==========");
fixUslugi(list);
System.out.println("Dedup!");
list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

```
Uslugi(id=1, polis=p1, fio=John, date_obsl=Fri Mar 17 13:28:19 EET 2023, code_usl=usl1, kol_usl=0, correct=false)
Uslugi(id=2, polis=p2, fio=Jane, date_obsl=Fri Mar 17 12:28:19 EET 2023, code_usl=usl2, kol_usl=0, correct=false)
Uslugi(id=3, polis=p1, fio=John, date_obsl=Fri Mar 17 12:28:19 EET 2023, code_usl=usl1, kol_usl=0, correct=false)
Uslugi(id=4, polis=p1, fio=John, date_obsl=Thu Mar 16 13:28:19 EET 2023, code_usl=usl3, kol_usl=0, correct=false)
Uslugi(id=5, polis=p3, fio=John, date_obsl=Fri Mar 17 16:28:19 EET 2023, code_usl=usl1, kol_usl=0, correct=false)
Uslugi(id=6, polis=p2, fio=Jane, date_obsl=Fri Mar 17 15:28:19 EET 2023, code_usl=usl2, kol_usl=0, correct=false)
Uslugi(id=7, polis=p3, fio=John, date_obsl=Fri Mar 17 14:28:19 EET 2023, code_usl=usl2, kol_usl=0, correct=false)
Uslugi(id=8, polis=p3, fio=John, date_obsl=Fri Mar 17 11:28:19 EET 2023, code_usl=usl3, kol_usl=0, correct=false)
==========
Dedup!
Uslugi(id=4, polis=p1, fio=John, date_obsl=Thu Mar 16 13:28:19 EET 2023, code_usl=usl3, kol_usl=1, correct=true)
Uslugi(id=3, polis=p1, fio=John, date_obsl=Fri Mar 17 12:28:19 EET 2023, code_usl=usl1, kol_usl=2, correct=true)
Uslugi(id=1, polis=p1, fio=John, date_obsl=Fri Mar 17 13:28:19 EET 2023, code_usl=usl1, kol_usl=0, correct=false)
Uslugi(id=2, polis=p2, fio=Jane, date_obsl=Fri Mar 17 12:28:19 EET 2023, code_usl=usl2, kol_usl=2, correct=true)
Uslugi(id=6, polis=p2, fio=Jane, date_obsl=Fri Mar 17 15:28:19 EET 2023, code_usl=usl2, kol_usl=0, correct=false)
Uslugi(id=8, polis=p3, fio=John, date_obsl=Fri Mar 17 11:28:19 EET 2023, code_usl=usl3, kol_usl=1, correct=true)
Uslugi(id=7, polis=p3, fio=John, date_obsl=Fri Mar 17 14:28:19 EET 2023, code_usl=usl2, kol_usl=1, correct=true)
Uslugi(id=5, polis=p3, fio=John, date_obsl=Fri Mar 17 16:28:19 EET 2023, code_usl=usl1, kol_usl=1, correct=true)
```

***Замечание: В последнем обновлении в группировку было добавлено поле `kod_usl`***

---

Вариант со Stream API

Можно использовать коллектор `Collectors.toMap`, чтобы сгруппировать данные по нужному ключу, при этом потребуется либо создать отдельный класс для ключа, либо в "ленивом" варианте обойтись списком объектов.
Также потребуется изменять состояние объектов внутри списка, в том числе при помощи функции слияния разных экземпляров услуг, соответствующих одинаковому ключу.   Поэтому такое решение будет использовать побочный эффект, и поэтому не рекомендуется с точки зрения чистоты функционального кода.

```java
public static void fixUslugiStream(List<Uslugi> list) {
    if (null == list || list.size() < 2) {
        return;  // изменения не нужны для таких входных данных
    }

    list.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Uslugi::getPolis)
            .thenComparing(Uslugi::getFio)
            .thenComparing(Uslugi::getDate_obsl)
            .thenComparing(Uslugi::getCode_usl)
        )
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            MyClass::key,      // ключ по нужным полям
            MyClass::mapFirst, // изменили состояние первого объекта
            MyClass::merge     // функция слияния в случае совпадения ключа
        ));
}

// class MyClass
// Функции для коллектора toMap
public static List<Object> key(Uslugi uslugi) {
    return Arrays.asList(
        new java.sql.Date(uslugi.getDate_obsl().getTime()).toLocalDate(),
        uslugi.getPolis(),
        uslugi.getFio(),
        uslugi.getCode_usl()
    );
}

public static Uslugi mapFirst(Uslugi uslugi) {
    uslugi.setCorrect(true); 
    uslugi.setKol_usl(1);
    return uslugi;
}

public static Uslugi merge(Uslugi u1, Uslugi u2) {
    u1.setKol_usl(u1.getKol_usl() + 1);
    u2.setCorrect(false);
    u2.setKol_usl(0);
    return u1;
}
```

Замечание: в решении со Stream API входной список *не будет* отсортирован.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, применю первый вариант, он нагляднее и проще в понимании мне кажется.

Comment: Циклы более привычны :)  А так код со стримами проще - в частности за счёт сокращения дублированного кода при вычислении и проверке ключа.

Comment: Последний вопрос можно в первом варианте i = j что нам дает?

Comment: Увеличивается индекс во внешнем цикле, чтобы пропустить уже обработанные дубликаты.  Переписал еще стримовое решение, заменив лямбды ссылками на соответствующие методы.

Comment: Поняла, спасибо

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, а если класс Uslugi содержит больше полей, чем я для примера здесь привела, нужно ли в сравнение вносить какие-то дополнительные условия? Я запустила ваш код с обычным циклом для своего класса, который имеет больше полей и он разные услуги отсекает

Comment: Код не отсекает _разные_ услуги, он их объединяет все под какой-то одной.  Как я указал, можно сгруппировать дополнительно по коду услуги как минимум.  Также можно считать не только общее количество услуг, но и к примеру суммировать их стоимость (если у вас например есть скидки за несколько услуг).

Comment: Стоимость одна и та же, но вот в классе Uslugi есть множество доп. полей, которые я не указала к своему сожалению хотела упростить код для понимания. При сравнении указала как у вас полис, дата и фамилия, но почему-то первая услуга пациента проходит нормально correct = true, остальные за этот день false.

Comment: Вы знаете, если в вашем указать одну и ту же дату, то ваш код неправильно отрабатывает. Во входных данных вместо дат, которые вы указали я указала просто new Date(), чтобы одна и таже дата подставлялась (на выходе я проверяла одна и та же дата), то ваш код все равно отсекает разные услуги, даже если они были выполнены в один день одному пациенту

Comment: Так это требование из вопроса: `А для остальных таких услуг, которые были сделаны в поле correct поставить значение false.`

Comment: Что значит _код отсекает разные услуги_?

Comment: Я имела ввиду следующее: если в один день пациенту одна и та же услуга была оказана несколько раз, то отсекать все кроме одной. а если в один есть разные услуги, то не отсекать. только дублирующиеся отсекать.

Comment: отсекает разные услуги имею ввиду разные коды услуг, если встречаются у пациента в один день, то для всех кроме первой ставится false

Comment: Я ведь об этом ещё вчера написал -- ***Вероятно, следует добавить в группировку поле `kod_usl`***  Код в ответе соответствует первоначальному вопросу.

Comment: я так пробовала тоже. еще раз перепроверю как у компа буду.

Comment: Обновил код и результаты теста

Comment: Сработало, спасибо. Видимо я в условии только в одном месте добавила проверку на код. У меня код, который вы привели выполняется в зависимости от условия два раза